# Transparent png image not showing as transparent in Xamarin Absolute Layout

Tags: forms, xaml, xamarin, png, transparent

Transparent png image not showing as transparent in Xamarin Absolute Layout

```
<AbsoluteLayout BackgroundColor="Aqua">
        <Image Source="@drawable/icon.png" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,30,30" 
               AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
 </AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: is it showing at all?  that is not typically how you specify an image source

Comment: Yes the image is being shown at the center of screen with grey background.

Comment: could you show a screenshot ?Is your icon.png transparent ?

Answer (score 1):

Just change your background color to transparent in your `<Image>`.

Something like that.

```
 <Image Source="@drawable/icon.png" BackgroundColor="Transparent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,30,30" 
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" />
```